# Activate only one card when using the handleEvent

Tags: reactjs, meteor, material-ui

I'm rendering from the database a list of elements (every element has own attributes etc), the problem is then when I press the function that opens the card it opens all. I don't know how to solve it. I was thinking of using a variable but I don't know where to put it.

Functions used to open the card

```
const handleExpandClick = () => {
    setExpanded(!expanded);
};

const handleOpenModal = () => {
    setOpenModal(true);
};

const handleCloseModal = () => {
    setOpenModal(false);
};
```

The return statement

```
<Grid container className={classes.fondo}>
        <Paper>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Button onClick={handleOpenModal} variant="contained" color="primary">Nueva casa de dia</Button>
        </Grid>

                <Grid item xs={12}>
                    <Grid container spacing={3}>
                    {casasDeDia.map((casa) => (
                        <Grid item>
                            <Card className={classes.root}>
                                <CardHeader
                                    title={casa.nombre}
                                    subheader={"Apertura "+casa.horarioApertura + "- Cierre " + casa.horarioCierre}
                                />
                                <CardMedia
                                    className={classes.media}
                                    image={casa.foto}
                                    title={casa.nombre}
                                />
                                <CardContent>
                                    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
                                        {casa.direccion}
                                </Typography>
                                </CardContent>
                                <CardActions disableSpacing>
                                    <IconButton aria-label="editar">
                                        <DeleteIcon />
                                    </IconButton>
                                    <IconButton aria-label="eliminar">
                                        <EditIcon />
                                    </IconButton>
                                    <IconButton
                                        className={clsx(classes.expand, {
                                            [classes.expandOpen]: expanded,
                                        })}
                                        onClick={handleExpandClick}
                                        aria-expanded={expanded}
                                        aria-label="mostrar mas"
                                    >
                                        <ExpandMoreIcon />
                                    </IconButton>
                                </CardActions>
                                <Collapse in={expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                                    <CardContent>
                                        <Typography paragraph>Direccion:</Typography>
                                        <Typography paragraph>
                                            {casa.direccion}
                                        </Typography>
                                        <Typography paragraph>Restricciones:</Typography>
                                        <Typography paragraph>
                                            <List>
                                                {
                                                    (casa.restricciones).map((restriccion) => (
                                                        <ListItem>
                                                            <Typography>
                                                                {restriccion}
                                                            </Typography>
                                                        </ListItem>

                                                    ))
                                                }
                                            </List>
                                        </Typography>
                                        <Typography paragraph>CupoLimite:</Typography>
                                        <Typography paragraph>
                                            {casa.cupoLimite}
                                        </Typography>
                                        <Typography paragraph>Actividades:</Typography>
                                        <List>
                                            {
                                                (casa.actividades).map((actividad) => (
                                                    <ListItem>
                                                        <Typography>
                                                            {actividad.nombre}
                                                        </Typography>
                                                    </ListItem>

                                                ))    
                                                }
                                            </List>
                                    </CardContent>
                                </Collapse>
                            </Card>
                        </Grid >
                ))}
                    </Grid>  
        </Grid>
            </Paper>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your current structure - you have 1 variable that controls **all** of the *cards* instead of 1 variable that controls **each** of the *cards*.
The variable (and functions) that control the opening of the Card are actually belong to the wrapper element (the grid).

Instead - what you should do is have a component that is in charge of 1 specific card. The functions and variable to control the state (open/close) of the card are inside that component, and this means that *each* card (component) has it's own stage.

```
default CardContainer = ({casa, classes}) => {
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

    const handleExpandClick = () => {
        setExpanded(!expanded);
    };
    const handleOpenModal = () => {
        setOpenModal(true);
    };
    const handleCloseModal = () => {
        setOpenModal(false);
    };

    return (
        <Card className={classes.root}>
            <CardHeader
                title={casa.nombre}
                subheader={"Apertura "+casa.horarioApertura + "- Cierre " + casa.horarioCierre}
            />
            <CardMedia
                className={classes.media}
                image={casa.foto}
                title={casa.nombre}
            />
            <CardContent>
                <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
                    {casa.direccion}
                </Typography>
            ...
            </CardContent>
        </Card>);
}
```

And inside your code you should use:

```
<Grid item xs={12}>
    <Grid container spacing={3}>
        {casasDeDia.map((casa) => (
            <Grid item>
                <CardContainer casa={casa} classes={classes} />
            </Grid>
        )}
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```